# C# performance of conditional versus memory allocation

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, .net-core, conditional-statements

Consider the following C# code:

```
IntPtr native = GetNativeError(/* parameters here */);
return new ManagedError(native);
```

Then the client code checks for error in the following way:

```
ManagedError err = /* get it with the code above */;
if(err.IsOk()) {
    /* Success */
}
```

A memory allocation here can be saved at the cost of an `if` statement:

```
IntPtr native = GetNativeError(/* parameters here */);
if(native == IntPtr.Zero) {
    return null;
} else {
    return new ManagedError(native);
}
```

Then the client code would check for the error as follows:

```
ManagedError err = /* get it with the code above */;
if(err == null) {
    /* Success */
}
```

My question is: which one of the approaches is faster? The first has additional memory allocation. The second has additional `if` statement.

UPDATE: I mean, in the success scenario. The error scenarios rarely happen and ok to be slow.

Comment: Since the number of times it returns null will be low compared to the number of times it allocates an object, this is probably going to be a negligible performance gain. Probably "premature optimisation".

Comment: @MatthewWatson Isn't it the opposite? Success == very common == zero allocation (null)

Comment: In general the second way is clearer, for me: a `ManagedError` that isn't an error but is a success is a `ManagedResult` (see `HRESULT`, `S_OK`)

Comment: Note that if `sizeof(ManagedError) <= IntPtr.Size` then making it a `struct` will make it "free" (because a `struct` with a size <= `IntPtr.Size` doesn't have any overhead against an `IntPtr` or a reference)

Comment: It is not clear what are your project requirements, but this is the way it is done in RCW: Error code is checked after a native invocation. If it is not S_OK, then exception is thrown. The exception contains the native error code among other things. This gives you the best of both worlds. No overhead if there is no error and all benefits of the exception processing if there is. You can read more about RCW here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @xanatos, it seems I can't make it a `struct` because I need a destructor to release the native handle.

Answer (score 7):

First off, **you wrote the code both ways already**.  If you want to know which way has better performance **run both programs and measure which one has better performance**.  That's the *only* way to answer a performance question accurately, so get out your stopwatch.

If you are unable to measure which one has better performance then plainly it doesn't matter which one has better performance, because the difference cannot be detected. An unobservable difference is irrelevant.

Now let's consider your specific problem.  Suppose you did decide to save a memory allocation in the common success case.  **The correct solution is not to give special meaning to null**.  The correct solution is to use the null object pattern.  That is **create a special instance of an object that is always used where you would otherwise use null**.

```
class ManagedError 
{
  public static readonly Success = new ManagedError(IntPtr.Zero);
  private ManagedError(IntPtr hr) { ... }
  public ManagedError FromNative(IntPtr hr) 
  {
    if (hr == IntPtr.Zero) return Success;
    return new ManagedError(hr);
  }
}
...
IntPtr native = GetNativeError(/* parameters here */);
return ManagedError.FromNative(native);
```

Done.  You always get a valid object, and you don't do any allocations in the common case.

Also, as mentioned in the other answer: why is this not a struct? **Why are you doing any reference type heap memory allocation at all**? If the thing is just a wrapper around an intptr then it should be a struct; it will be just as cheap to pass around as the intptr!

If you make it a struct then this gets even easier, because you just use the default instance of the struct as your null object!

```
struct ManagedError 
{
  public static readonly Success = default(ManagedError);
  private readonly IntPtr hr;
  public ManagedError(IntPtr hr) { this.hr = hr }
}
```

And you're done; no heap allocation at all. You just wrap up the intptr.

Answer (score 1):

In general the second way is clearer, for me: a `ManagedError` that isn't an error but is a success is a `ManagedResult` (see for example the COM API that use an `HRESULT`, that can be `S_OK` (or in general `S_*`) or `E_*` (`E_FAIL` for example).

I'll say that in general allocating an useless object isn't a good idea... But it isn't even a bad idea (the overhead is very small, because if the object is very shortlived the GC will destroy it immediately). Still it is against .NET patterns (that use `Exception` to return an error, or `bool`)... So even here I don't see a big plus or a big minus.

Note that if `sizeof(ManagedError) <= IntPtr.Size` then making it a `struct` will make it "free" to allocate and pass around (because a `struct` with a `sizeof <= IntPtr.Size` doesn't have any overhead against an `IntPtr` or in general against managed reference)